# Porting an old C++ code from Solaris to Linux

Tags: c++, linux, static, solaris

I am just wondering if this type of declaration is allowed in C++

```
  static nextUnassignedTableID = 0; 
  static nextUnassignedFieldID = TSFID_MINIMUM_USER_TSFID;
```

It doesn't complain about anything on Solaris/AIX.

But, on Red Hat Enterprise Linux, it complains about

```
 TSIDConverter.cpp(637): error #303: explicit type is missing ("int" assumed)
 static nextUnassignedTableID = 0; 

 TSIDConverter.cpp(638): error #303: explicit type is missing ("int" assumed)
 static nextUnassignedFieldID = TSFID_MINIMUM_USER_TSFID;
```

On Linux, I am using Intel 11.1 compiler with the command icpc -m32.

Should I include other libs in order for it to compiler, or is this style of declaration not allowed anymore?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's pretty much never been allowed. The first C++ standard disallowed the C "implicit int" rule; C99 also got rid of that rule. But the rule is simple, and fixing the code is also simple: just stick `int` in wherever the compiler complains. Tedious, perhaps, but straightforward.

Comment: This code has been used since 2005, and it seems to be working fine on Solaris and AIX. On Solaris, the gcc compiler is gcc version 2.95.3 20010315 (release), and on AIX, it is xlc_r version 5.0

Comment: Hi @roymustang86, meet `gcc -ansi -pedantic -Wall`. Also, gcc 4.6 is considered 'current' for gcc. 4.7 is already out. When I worked on AIX 5.x two years back, we upgraded from XlC++ 8 to 9, I believe.

Comment: @roymustang86 - both of those compilers are from the early 2000's; the first C++ standard was 1998, and compilers back in those days tended to support pre-standard code to make the transition easier.

Answer (score 1):

`Default int` is not allowed in C++, you need to fix this code and set an explicit `int` type for variables.